# How to use values stored in variables as case patterns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, switch-statement, python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

I'm trying to understand the new [structural pattern matching](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/) syntax in Python 3.10. I understand that it is possible to match on literal values like this:

```py
def handle(retcode):
    match retcode:
        case 200:
            print('success')
        case 404:
            print('not found')
        case _:
            print('unknown')

handle(404)
# not found
```

However, if I refactor and move these values to module-level variables, it results in an error because the statements now represent structures or patterns rather than values:

```py
SUCCESS = 200
NOT_FOUND = 404

def handle(retcode):
    match retcode:
        case SUCCESS:
            print('success')
        case NOT_FOUND:
            print('not found')
        case _:
            print('unknown')

handle(404)
#  File "<ipython-input-2-fa4ae710e263>", line 6
#    case SUCCESS:
#         ^
# SyntaxError: name capture 'SUCCESS' makes remaining patterns unreachable
```

Is there any way to use the match statement to match values that are stored within variables?

Comment: My reading of PEP-635 suggests you need a value pattern, which appears to be defined as a *dotted* name. I'm not sure why you would get a syntax error here, though, as `SUCCESS` should be interpreted as a capture pattern.

Comment: *"an unqualified name (i.e. a bare name with no dots) will be always interpreted as a capture pattern"*

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If the constant you're testing against is a dotted name, then it should be treated as a constant instead of as the name of the variable to put the capture in (see [PEP 636 # Matching against constants and enums](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/#matching-against-constants-and-enums)):

```
class Codes:
    SUCCESS = 200
    NOT_FOUND = 404

def handle(retcode):
    match retcode:
        case Codes.SUCCESS:
            print('success')
        case Codes.NOT_FOUND:
            print('not found')
        case _:
            print('unknown')
```

Although, given how python is trying to implement *pattern-matching*, I think that for situations like this it's probably safer and clearer code to just use an `if/elif/else` tower when checking against constant values.

Comment: I think this is only less clear because no body is used to `match` statements yet. I suspect the implementation can perform pattern matching more efficiently than the linear search imposed by an `if` tower.

Comment: @chepner given the specification it can't be faster than the linear `if` tower (and that's how it's implemented currently).  the cases must be evaluated in order due to precedence rules

Comment: Can you elaborate on "given how python is trying to implement pattern-matching"? What about the how would make it less safe or less clear than if/else?

Answer (score 47):

Hopefully I can help shed some light on *why* bare names work this way here.

First, as others have already noted, if you need to match values as part of your patterns, you can do so by:

- Matching supported literals, like numbers, strings, booleans, and `None`
- Matching qualified (dotted) names
- Using additional tests in guards (which are separated from patterns by `if`)

I fear that we (the PEP authors) probably made a small error by including this toy snippet in an early tutorial... it's since gone a bit viral. Our goal was to lead with the simplest possible example of pattern matching, but we instead seem to have also created a confusing first impression for many (especially when repeated without context).

**The most overlooked word in the title of these PEPs is "structural". If you're not matching the *structure* of the subject, *structural* pattern matching probably isn't the right tool for the job.**

The design of this feature was driven by destructuring (like iterable unpacking on the LHS of assignments, but generalized for all objects), which is why we made it very easy to perform the core functionality of extracting out parts of an object and binding them to names. We *also* decided that it would also be useful to allow programmers to match on values, so we added those (with the condition that when the values are named, they must be qualified with a dot, in order to distinguish them from the more common extractions).

Python's pattern matching was never really designed with the intent of powering C-style switch statements like this; that's been proposed for Python (and rejected) twice before, so we chose to go in a different direction. Besides, there is already one obvious way to switch on a single value, which is simpler, shorter, and works on every version of Python: a good-ol' `if`/`elif`/`else` ladder!

```py
SUCCESS = 200
NOT_FOUND = 404

def handle(retcode):
    if retcode == SUCCESS:
        print('success')
    elif retcode == NOT_FOUND:
        print('not found')
    else:
        print('unknown')

handle(404)
```

(If you're really concerned about performance or need an expression, dispatching from a dictionary is also a fine alternative.)

Comment: This answer clarified a lot to me.  I don't know if PEPs are amendable once final, but I think a clearer point on "why this is not a switch/case statement and should not be used as one" could avoid a lot of confusion.  At least [the "what's new in Python" docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#simple-pattern-match-to-a-literal) can be amended still for sure :)

Comment: one option would be to have a syntax like `case =SUCCESS:` or similar, where the `=` denotes that the numeric value of `SUCCESS` should be used for pattern matching (or maybe `case .SUCCESS` to indicate that `SUCCESS` should be treated as a "dotted" variable).

Comment: Adding on to gerrit's statement, even in the official Python docs, it says `match` is for `pattern matching`, not `structural pattern matching` https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-match-statement.

Answer (score 24):

Aside from using *literal* values, the [Value Patterns](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0635/#value-patterns) section of PEP 635 mentions the use of *dotted names* or the use of *guards*. See below for comparison:

**Literal values**

```py
def handle(code):
    match code:
        case 200:
            print('success')
        case 404:
            print('not found')
        case _:
            print('unknown')
```

References:

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0635/#literal-patterns
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/#matching-specific-values

**Dotted names**

> Any dotted name (i.e. attribute access) is interpreted as a value pattern.

```py
class StatusCodes:
    OK = 200
    NOT_FOUND = 404

def handle(code):
    match code:
        case StatusCodes.OK:
            print('success')
        case StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND:
            print('not found')
        case _:
            print('unknown')
```

References:

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0635/#value-patterns
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/#matching-against-constants-and-enums

**Guards**

> [A] guard is an arbitrary expression attached to a pattern and that must evaluate to a "truthy" value for the pattern to succeed.

```py
SUCCESS = 200
NOT_FOUND = 404

def handle(code):
    match code:
        case status if status == SUCCESS:
            print('success')
        case status if status == NOT_FOUND:
            print('not found')
        case _:
            print('unknown')
```

References:

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0635/#guards
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/#adding-conditions-to-patterns

Answer (score 9):

Python's `match` is much more than a simple switch statement. If you use bare what you consider "variable names", they are actually going to be [Capture Patterns](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/#capture-patterns). <sup>as per definition in [PEP no. 634](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634)</sup>

Besides the fact that you should probably not use `match` for your use case, you have to use *qualified* (dotted) names in one of the following ways:

### #1 Flat Object

```py
statuses = object()
statuses.success = 200
status.not_found = 404

def handle(retcode):
    match retcode:
        case statuses.success: print("Success")
        case statuses.not_found: print("Not found")
```

### #2 Object Oriented Programming

```py
class StatusValues:
    success = 200
    not_found = 404

def handle(retcode):
    match retcode:
        case StatusValues.success: print("Success")
        case StatusValues.not_found: print("Not found")
```

### #3 Simple qualified locals()/globals() access

I've developed [the match-ref library](https://github.com/squirrel-preslash/match-ref) which allows you to access any local or global variable in- or outside of any function, simply using the `ref.` prefix.

```py
from matchref import ref
import random

SUCCESS = 200
NOT_FOUND = 404

def handle(retcode):
    random_code = random.randint(600,699)

    match retcode:
        case ref.SUCCESS: print("Success")
        case ref.NOT_FOUND: print("Not found")
        case ref.random_code: print("OK, you win!")
```

As you can see, `ref` automatically resolved variables from your local and global namespaces (in this order). There's no additional setup necessary.

If you don't want to use 3rd-party libraries, you can see a slightly similar no-libraries version below.

### #4 Qualified locals()/globals() access without 3rd-party libs

[`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) and [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) are built-in functions in Python which return a `dict` containing all your variable names mapped to their respective values. You need to be able to access the dict's values using dotted syntax, since `match` also does not support dictionary access syntax. You can therefore write this simple helper class:

```py
class GetAttributeDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self[name]
```

and use it like so:

```py
import random

SUCCESS = 200
NOT_FOUND = 404

def handle(retcode):
    random_code = random.randint(600, 699)
    globs = GetAttributeDict(globals())
    locs = GetAttributeDict(locals())

    match retcode:
        case globs.SUCCESS: print("Success")
        case globs.NOT_FOUND: print("Not found")
        case locs.random_code: print("OK , you win!")
```

### #5 Module Access

Given that you seem to intend to re-use your status codes (because otherwise you could inline them in your `case` s), you might consider using separate modules for this.

`constants.py:`

```py
SUCCESS = 200
NOT_FOUND = 404
```

`main.py`

```py
import constants

match retcode:
    case constants.SUCCESS: ...
    ...
```

---

Again, you might want to reconsider if you want to use `match` at all.

Comment: The example code in #1 doesn't work because `object()` instances don't allow assigning custom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to use the match statement to match values that are stored within variables?

You can do this in other languages with immutable data types.

The match statement in python rebinds the values to the variables when possible, so they will match.

To avoid this, use literals or dotted structures. Sometimes it is just easier to use guards or an `if` statement.

Answer (score -2):

python > `3.10` lets you handle case patterns more efficiently.

`|` and `if` statements can be used as well.

using `|`

```
match name: 
    case "example_111" | "example_222": 
        return f"Hello {name}" 
    case _: 
        return "Bye"
```

using `if` statement

```
def get_product_info(make, in_dollar): 

    match make:

        case "product_111" if in_dollar: 
            return "10000 $"

        case "product_222" if not in_dollar:
            return "10000*73 INR"

        case _: 
            return "error"
```