# How to use match case with a class type

Tags: python, class, types, match, case

I want to use `match` to determine an action to perform based on a class `type`. I cannot seem to figure out how to do it. I know their are other ways of achieving this, I would just like to know can it be done this way. I am not looking for workarounds of which there are many.

```
class aaa():
    pass

class bbb():
    pass

def f1(typ):
    if typ is aaa:
        print("aaa")
    elif typ is bbb:
        print("bbb")
    else:
        print("???")

def f2(typ):
    match typ:
        case aaa():
            print("aaa")
        case bbb():
            print("bbb")
        case _:
            print("???")

f1(aaa)
f1(bbb)
f2(aaa)
f2(bbb)
```

The output is as follows:

```
aaa
bbb
???
???
```

Comment: I would like to be able to do this for abstract classes too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `typ()` instead of `typ` in the `match` line:

```py
        class aaa():
            pass

        class bbb():
            pass

        def f1(typ):
            if typ is aaa:
                print("aaa")
            elif typ is bbb:
                print("bbb")
            else:
                print("???")

        def f2(typ):
            match typ():
                case aaa():
                    print("aaa")
                case bbb():
                    print("bbb")
                case _:
                    print("???")

        f1(aaa)
        f1(bbb)
        f2(aaa)
        f2(bbb)
```

Output:

```
aaa
bbb
aaa
bbb
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on OP's comment asking for solution that works for classes more generally than the example classes in the question, here is an answer addressing this:

```py
class aaa():
    pass

class bbb():
    pass

def f1(typ):
    if typ is aaa:
        print("aaa")
    elif typ is bbb:
        print("bbb")
    else:
        print("???")

def f2(typ):
    match typ.__qualname__:
        case aaa.__qualname__:
            print("aaa")
        case bbb.__qualname__:
            print("bbb")
        case _:
            print("???")

f1(aaa)
f1(bbb)
f2(aaa)
f2(bbb)
```

Output:

```
aaa
bbb
aaa
bbb
```

**UPDATE #2:**
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67525257/capture-makes-remaining-patterns-unreachable) post and some perusal of PEP 364 [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/#capture-patterns), I have created an example showing how a few data types (a Python builtin, a class from the collections module, and a user defined class) can be used by `match` to determine an action to perform based on a class type (or more generally, a data type):

```py
class bbb:
    pass

class namespacing_class:
    class aaa:
        pass


def f1(typ):
    if typ is aaa:
        print("aaa")
    elif typ is bbb:
        print("bbb")
    else:
        print("???")

def f2(typ):
    match typ.__qualname__:
        case aaa.__qualname__:
            print("aaa")
        case bbb.__qualname__:
            print("bbb")
        case _:
            print("???")

def f3(typ):
    import collections
    match typ:
        case namespacing_class.aaa:
            print("aaa")
        case __builtins__.str:
            print("str")
        case collections.Counter:
            print("Counter")
        case _:
            print("???")

'''
f1(aaa)
f1(bbb)
f2(aaa)
f2(bbb)
'''
f3(namespacing_class.aaa)
f3(str)
import collections
f3(collections.Counter)
```

Outputs:

```
aaa
str
Counter
```

As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67525259/18135454) answer in another post:

> A variable name in a case clause is treated as a [name capture pattern](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/#capture-patterns). It always matches and tries to make an assignment to the variable name. ... We need to replace the name capture pattern with a non-capturing pattern such as a [value pattern](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/#value-patterns) that uses the . operator for attribute lookup. The dot is the key to matching this a non-capturing pattern.

In other words, if we try to say `case aaa:` for example, `aaa` will be interpreted as a name to which we assign the subject (`typ` in your code) and will always match and block any attempts to match subsequent `case` lines.

To get around this, for class type names (or names generally) that can be specified using a dot (perhaps because they belong to a namespace or another class), we can use the dotted name as a pattern that will not be interpreted as a name capture.

For built-in type `str`, we can use `case __builtins__.str:`. For the `Counter` class in Python's `collections` module, we can use `case collections.Counter:`. If we define class `aaa` within another class named `namespacing_class`, we can use `case namespacing_class.aaa:`.

However, if we define class `bbb` at the top level within our Python code, it's not clear to me that there is any way to use a dotted name to refer to it and thereby avoid name capture.

It's possible there's a way to specify a user defined class `type` in a `case` line and I simply haven't figured it out yet. Otherwise, it seems rather arbitrary (and unfortunate) to be able to do this for dottable types and not for non-dottable ones.

Comment: Works in that example but doesn't for abstract classes

Comment: Or if there is an `__init__` with non optional arguments. Anyway I don't want to instantiate classes unnecessarily.

Comment: OK, probably a good idea to update your question accordingly.

Comment: @pauleohare Take a look at my updated answer, which does not instantiate any classes.

Comment: Sorry, my question should be clearer. Your answer does work but the reason I asked the question was to find out if I can match on class type not to find a workaround.

Comment: @pauleohare Have you seen this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67525257/capture-makes-remaining-patterns-unreachable>? Please see my updated answer for an example of using `match` to determine an action to perform based on a class `type`. It shows that it can work (but you probably won't like the restrictive applicability).

Comment: Thanks. You are right, I don't like it, but thank you very much for your answer and it's completeness. I guess I'll probably stick with ifs and elifs against types.

Comment: matching on `__builtins__.set` doesn't work, `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'set'`

Answer (score 6):

You want to match against a constant value. That's a case for [constant value patterns](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#constant-value-patterns):

```
match typ:
    case somemodule.ClassOne:
        ...
    case anothermodule.ClassTwo:
        ...
```

Constant value patterns must be of the form `NAME ('.' NAME)+` - that is, a name followed by at least one attribute lookup. A bare name will be considered a capture pattern. That's fine for classes defined in other modules, but if you want to match against classes in the same module, you can import the current module:

```
# in somemodule.py
import somemodule

class ClassOne:
    ...
class ClassTwo:
    ...

match typ:
    case somemodule.ClassOne:
        ...
    case somemodule.ClassTwo:
...
```

or if you want to avoid the circular import, you can create a namespace:

```
import types

options = types.SimpleNamespace()
options.ClassOne = ClassOne
options.ClassTwo = ClassTwo

match typ:
    case options.ClassOne:
        ...
    case options.ClassTwo:
        ...
```

Note that if you go the "import the current module" route, you need to be aware of Python's weird thing where the entry point script is considered the `__main__` module, regardless of its file name. If you do `python somefile.py` and try to `import somefile` inside that, it will perform a *second* run of `somefile.py` as the `somefile` module and create a second copy of all your classes, and your match statements won't work.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an `if` guard in the relevant cases?

```py
class aaa():
    pass

class bbb():
    pass

def f(typ):
    match typ:
        case aaa():
            print("aaa instance")
        case bbb():
            print("bbb instance")
        case _aaa if _aaa is aaa:
            print("aaa class")
        case _bbb if _bbb is bbb:
            print("bbb class")
        case _:
            print("???")

f(aaa())
f(bbb())
f(aaa)
f(bbb)
```

```
# output:
aaa instance
bbb instance
aaa class
bbb class
```

Reference: See the [Adding conditions to patterns](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#adding-conditions-to-patterns) section of PEP 636.