# Matching pygame events

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, switch-statement

The following works:

```python
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        match (event.type):
            case pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
```

but if I write without "pygame." in the case expression

```python
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        match (event.type):
            case QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
```

the case catches all the events and not only the QUIT one. Other potential cases are also marked unreachable by python.

Why is that? `print(pygame.QUIT)` and `print(QUIT)` both display "256".

Comment: What version of Python are you using, when I try something similar in Python 3.10.5, I encounter a `Syntax Error: name capture 'QUIT' makes remaining patterns unreachable`. Looking up this error takes me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67525259/2280890) which basically says you need to use dotted names. So I'd skip the * import.

Comment: @importrandom Interesting, I'm on 3.10.5 too

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the `QUIT` keyword if you only had imported pygame, to use only `QUIT` you need to also import pygame locals:

```
import pygame # Default
from pygame.locals import * # Optional
```

Then you can use either `pygame.QUIT` or `QUIT`.

Also instead of matching these events you can use:

```
for event in pygame.event.get(): # Handle events
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # Check if the X button is clicked
        pygame.quit() # Quit pygame
```

Then you just only need to `import pygame`

Comment: Thanks for answering. Well that's my whole point, if you import * from pygame.locals, and then use only QUIT on the match, it doesn't work! Why is that?