# Python match statement on types

Tags: python, match

I normally do not use match statements, but I had an opportunity.

I have a variable which can be of different data *types*, and I want to match on the type to do different things.  This toy example captures the essence of what I want to do:

```py
lang = "Python"
match type(lang):
  case str:
    print("It is a string.")
  case _:
    print("It is something else.")

SyntaxError: name capture 'str' makes remaining patterns unreachable
```

My understanding of the match statement and [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67525259/534238) made me think that I could not use a *variable*, but I am not using a variable here, I am using a *type*.  It *seems like* `str` is being treated like a variable.

I just tested it, and in fact I *can* overwrite `str` (I assumed it was a keyword):

```py
>>> str = 7
>>> str
7
>>> str(14)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

OK. So that (likely) explains what is going on. But how can I avoid it?  How can I tell `match` to not smash over `str`? Is this something that just cannot be done in `match` statements?

I have plenty of other ways to solve the problem. I was just surprised that the first time I tried to use `match`, somehow I already "broke" it and found a weakness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `case type`, use `case type()`. Also, replace `type(lang)` with just `lang` in the match statement.

```py
lang = "Python"
match lang:
  case str():
    print("It is a string.")
  case _:
    print("It is something else.")
```

This will match any instance of type `str`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  Honestly, I'm not sure why this works, though:  `str()` should be creating an empty string, `''`.  And an empty string does not match `"Python"`.  But it works.

Comment: I like to think of it as checking if the lang matches "an instance of a `type`", the same way one might use the `isinstance` function. However, this has a lot more power as you can, for example, say `case A(b=1)` and this will match instances of class `A` with the attribute `b` set to `1`. Although, I agree, it does seem a little unintuitive at first.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the explanation!  It seems like Python is trying to imitate the power of pattern matching in other languages like Haskell, but I feel like it is a little "shoehorned" and not fully elegant.