# How to use Python pattern matching to match class types?

Tags: python, structural-pattern-matching

How can we use Python's structural pattern matching (introduced in 3.10) to match the type of a variable without invoking the constructor / in a case where a new instantiation of the class is not easily possible?

The following code fails:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

# instantiation requires 'name' to be defined
class Tree(BaseModel):
    name: str

my_plant = Tree(name='oak')


match type(my_plant):
    case Tree:
        print('My plant is a tree.')
    case _:
        print('error')
```

with error message `SyntaxError: name capture 'Tree' makes remaining patterns unreachable`

An alternative attempt was to re-create an instance during matching (dangerous because of instantiation during matching, but worth a shot...) - it also fails:

```
match type(my_plant):
    case type(Tree()):
        print('My plant is a tree.')
    case _:
        print('error')

TypeError: type() accepts 0 positional sub-patterns (1 given)
```

Checking against an instance of `Tree()` resolves the SyntaxError, but does not lead to working output, because it always produces "error". I do not want to use the workaround to match against a derived `bool` (e.g., `type(my_plant) == Tree)`) because it would limit me to only compare 2 outcomes (True/False) not match against multiple class types.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#match-statements

Comment: Sorry, please help me out here... Your comment is not exactly self-explanatory. I don't see any reference to type in the documentation - only a "function definition" part. Are you implying I should use separate helper functions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture makes remaining patterns unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67525257/capture-makes-remaining-patterns-unreachable)

Comment: You’re looking for the 3rd example in that tutorial: `match point: case Point():`.

Comment: I don't get it... The referenced "point" example matches the VALUE of an instance 'point' against the value of a new instance of 'Point". I am trying to match the type. I really struggle to see how they are related. Can you rewrite the example code to make it work?

Comment: What is in `case` is not an instance, it is a pattern. It just (somewhat confusingly) looks like an instance. `case Tree():` matches against all instances of class `Tree`, not against some newly created instance of `Tree`.

Comment: `match my_plant: case Tree():` is what you want.

Comment: Wow - so you DO have to instantiate during the matching? And what if we cannot create a new instance? Say you have a custom class with (a) pydantic requiring specific fields and/or (b) and expensive init function? Then instantiating `Tree()` just to match the type of `my_plant` (which is already defined) is really not an option

Comment: It does *not* create a new instance! The syntax just looks like it. This is all written in the tutorial…

Comment: [PEP 636](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#adding-a-ui-matching-objects) has an example on matching objects.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question to include the explicit example of "pydantic" prohibiting an simple instantiation. Your answer works here, too, as you mentioned. It looks very weird to me that `Tree()` does not cause a pydantic error, but then again I will get used to the fact that that is not an instance but a pattern, despite the looks. Thank you

Comment: Well, pydantic also does not mark `"""Tree(!!!)"""` as an error. It knows that different rules apply in different contexts. Just like normal expression rules don't apply inside a string, case patterns have different rules than expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on what I said in comments: `match` introduces a value, but `case` introduces a pattern to match against. It is not an expression that is evaluated. In case the pattern represents a class, the stuff in the parentheses is not passed to a constructor, but is matched against attributes of the `match` value. Here is an illustrative example:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.kind = name
    
def what_is(t):
    match t:
        case Tree(kind="oak"):
            return "oak"
        case Tree():
            return "tree"
        case _:
            return "shrug"

print(what_is(Tree(name="oak")))    # oak
print(what_is(Tree(name="birch")))  # tree
print(what_is(17))                  # shrug
```

Note here that outside `case`, `Tree(kind="oak")` would be an error:

```
TypeError: Tree.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kind'
```

And, conversely, `case Tree(name="oak")` would never match, since `Tree` instances in my example would not normally have an attribute named `name`.

This proves that `case` does not invoke the constructor, even if it looks like an instantiation.

---

EDIT: About your second error: you wrote `case type(Tree()):`, and got `TypeError: type() accepts 0 positional sub-patterns (1 given)`. What happened here is this: `case type(...)` is, again, specifying a pattern. It is not evaluated as an expression. It says the match value needs to be of type `type` (i.e. be a class), and it has to have attributes in the parentheses. For example,

```
match Tree:
    case type(__init__=initializer):
        print("Tree is a type, and this is its initializer:")
        print(initializer)
```

This would match, and print something like

```
# => Tree is a type, and this is its initializer:
#    <function Tree.__init__ at 0x1098593a0>
```

The same `case` would *not* match an object of type `Tree`, only the type itself!

However, you can only use keyword arguments in this example. Positional arguments are only available if you define `__match_args__`, like the documentation says. The type `type` does not define `__match_args__`, and since it is an immutable built-in type, `case type(subpattern, ...)` (subpattern! *not* subexpression!), unlike `case type(attribute=subpattern, ...)`, will always produce an error.