# Why does a match-case statement assign to a variable used in one of the cases if the variable was not previously defined?

Tags: python, structural-pattern-matching

While learning pattern matching introduced in Python 10 I came across an example where a part of splitted string was being assigned/bound to a variable used in one of the cases.

```
match 'make dir'.split():
    case ["make"]:
       print("default make")
    case ["make", cmd]:
       print(f"make command found: {cmd}"}
    case ["restart"]:
       print("restarting")
    case ["rm", *files]:
       print (f"deleting files: {files}")
    case _:
       print("didn't match")
```

The second case has the previously undeclared variable `cmd`, which ends up being assigned the value `"dir"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pattern `["make", cmd]`, `cmd` is a *capture pattern*. Capture patterns (which look like un-dotted names such as `foo`, `bar`, or `cmd`) match *anything*, and unconditionally bind the matched value to that name.

In your example, any sequence of length 2 starting with `"make"` will bind the second element to `cmd` and execute the second `case` block. This is useful since it allows your app to easily determine which `make` command it should execute.

**This happens whether `cmd` is already assigned or not.** So, if it is already bound, that old value will be overwritten with the new, matched value.

If you want to *compare a name by value* instead, you have a couple of options depending on your situation:

- If the name is dotted (like `args.cmd` or `Class.VAR`), it will automatically compare by equality (and *not* capture). So you can just use `["make", args.cmd]` as your pattern.
- If the name is bare (like `cmd` or `VAR`), you can use a capture pattern together with a *guard* to compare by equality. Using this technique, your pattern could look like `["make", c] if c == cmd`. Note that since `c` is a capture pattern, it will be rebound just like `cmd` in your original example! (As you use pattern matching more, you'll find that capture patterns like `c` are extremely useful when performing more complex pattern matches.)

I recommend that anybody looking to familiarize themselves with Python's structural pattern matching check out the [official tutorial](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/). It covers all of the different patterns (including capture patterns) in a very easy-to-understand way.

Comment: Can you please explain what is capture pattren? and what if I dont want the cmd variable to be bind with any value, but want to evaluate against vaule stored in cmd. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer to flesh out these ideas a bit. You may also be interested in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66190724/11278870).