# Unable to subtract in case pattern?

Tags: python, syntax-error, subtraction, python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

I'm trying to use Python 3.10 structural pattern matching in Python shell:

```py
match a:
   case (2 - 1):
```

after entering the second line, it gives me the following error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    case (2 - 1):
              ^
SyntaxError: imaginary number required in complex literal
```

NOTE: I know there's no code to execute after the `case`, I'm doing this in the shell and it throws this error immediately.
ALSO, I'm aware that I can store them as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66159622/13112843), but I'd rather do this directly if there is a way.

Comment: 2-1 is 1. Do you mean `case 1`?

Comment: Well, it's certainly an awful error message and should be reported as a bug.  But the case statement here requires a literal, not an expression.

Comment: @khelwood yes, I was simplifying from a more complex example that I was using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allowed to compute arbitrary expressions in a pattern. There's just too much room for conflict with other pattern syntax.

For example, there's little point doing `2 - 1` as a pattern. If you had a value stored in a variable `x`, you might want to match against `x - 1`:

```
case x - 1:
    ...
```

but consider what `case x` means:

```
case x:
    ...
```

`case x` means "match anything and set `x` equal to the thing matched". It would be extremely confusing for `case x` and `case x - 1` to do such extremely different things.

The error message you got is because there's one special case where addition and subtraction are allowed in a pattern, as part of a complex number "literal":

```
case 1+2j:
    ...
```

An expression like `1+2j` or `1-2j` is syntactically an addition or subtraction expression, not a single literal, so Python has to allow this specific case of addition or subtraction to allow constant patterns with complex constants. The error message comes from Python expecting the `-` to be part of a complex constant.

If you want to match against a computed value, use a guard:

```
case x if x == arbitrary_expression:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are treating the pattern after `case` as a normal expression with a value, but it is in fact an entirely new syntactical category in Python; it looks like object construction (i.e. some literal, or a call to a constructor), but it is in fact the opposite, a pattern is used to destructure the object you're trying to match.

So, this works:

```
match x:
    case 1:
        print('one')
```

Because the literal `1` means specifically an `int` with the value of `1`. But `(2 - 1)` is an expression consisting of two literal integers, an operation and parentheses for grouping. Python tries to interpret it as a pattern and the pattern for destructuring a complex number comes closest.

For example:

```
n = 2 - 1j

match n:
    # these parentheses aren't needed, but allowed; 
    # they're here to show what Python thought you were trying to do
    case (2 - 1j):
        print('this number')
    case complex(real=r, imag=i):
        print('some other complex number')
```

As pointed out in the other answer, you can use a guard if you need to further restrict the value of what you're trying to match:

```
def try_this(n):
    match n:
        case int(x) if x == (2 - 1):
            print('what I want')
        case int(x):
            print('some other int')


try_this(1)
try_this(2)
```