# How to use python's Structural Pattern Matching to test built in types?

Tags: python, python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

I'm trying to use SPM to determine if a certain **type** is an `int` or an `str`.

The following code:

```py
from typing import Type

def main(type_to_match: Type):
    match type_to_match:
        case str():
            print("This is a String")
        case int():
            print("This is an Int")
        case _:
            print("\nhttps://en.meming.world/images/en/0/03/I%27ve_Never_Met_This_Man_In_My_Life.jpg")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_type = str
    main(test_type)
```

returns https://en.meming.world/images/en/0/03/I%27ve_Never_Met_This_Man_In_My_Life.jpg

Most of the documentation I found talks about how to test if a certain variable is an instance of a type. But not how to test if a type is of a certain type.

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Comparing types directly is usually more restrictive than you want. I would consider `if issubclass(type_to_match, str):`, etc, to allow for subclass matching.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you just pass a type directly, it will consider it to be a "name capture" rather than a "value capture." You can coerce it to use a value capture by importing the `builtins` module, and using a dotted notation to check for the type.

```py
import builtins
from typing import Type


def main(type_: Type):
    match (type_):
        case builtins.str:  # it works with the dotted notation
            print(f"{type_} is a String")
        case builtins.int:
            print(f"{type_} is an Int")
        case _:
            print("\nhttps://en.meming.world/images/en/0/03/I%27ve_Never_Met_This_Man_In_My_Life.jpg")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(type("hello"))  # <class 'str'> is a String
    main(str)  # <class 'str'> is a String
    main(type(42))  # <class 'int'> is an Int
    main(int)  # <class 'int'> is an Int
```

Comment: there is absolutely no need to import builtins, or use `builtins.str` or `builtins.int`. Just use `str` and `int` in the case patterns. (yes, one can possibly override these names in the global namespace of the current module, but then, one should know what he is doing)

Comment: @jsbueno That wouldn't work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66159432/how-to-use-values-stored-in-variables-as-case-patterns. Using a bare name means the name for the capture. If you want to use a name as a constant, it has to be a dotted notation...

Comment: @jsbueno Compare the defintions of [capture patterns](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=case#capture-patterns) and [value patterns](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=case#value-patterns).

Comment: @jsbueno `case str` gives `SyntaxError: name capture 'str' makes remaining patterns unreachable`. If you have an actual working example, I would gladly see it.

Comment: @jsbueno, Like it was already stated, `case str` gives a syntax error.

Comment: You could, however, use an Enum or a class to encompass the "supported" types instead of importing something...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Wouldn't you need to import `Enum` for that?

Comment: Haha yeah I thought about that right after posting the comment.... Just a class with some class-level variables will have the same effect I guess... Just a matter of taste, works the same really (as your solution I mean)...

Comment: I stand corrected. Maybe I'd just use a guard with `issubclass` (if issubclass is the desired behavior) - `case type() if issubclass(type_, str)` - but then, indeed, for the exact class, `builtins.int` is a good solution.

Comment: @jsbueno Do you know how to match an `enum`?  For example, if I have a type `MyEnum`, and `MyOtherEnum` and I want to match either of them as a general enum? I tried doing `Enum()` but it didn't work.

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 `issubclass(MyEnum, Enum)`?

Comment: Enums might be tricky due to deep metaclass magic used in their construction. I will make some experiments here.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks! `case type_ if issubclass(type_,Enum)` works

Comment: yest, that from @Tomerikoo for _any- enum type. If you want to test for enum members of more than one type, use the `|` operator: `case Color() | Animal():`. If you want to test for a some specific enum classes, use the guard syntax and you might do:  `case type() if type(type_) in (Color, Animal):`

Answer (score 6):

As its name suggests, structural *pattern* matching is more suited for matching patterns, not values (like a classic `switch/case` in other languages). For example, it makes it very easy to check different possible structures of a list or a dict, but for values there is not much advantage over a simple `if/else` structure:

```py
if type_to_match == str:
    print("This is a String")
elif type_to_match == int:
    print("This is an Int")
else:
    print("\nhttps://en.meming.world/images/en/0/03/I%27ve_Never_Met_This_Man_In_My_Life.jpg")
```

But if you really want to use SPM, you could use [the guard feature](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0635/#guards) along with [`issublcass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass) to check if a type is or is a child of any other:

```py
match type_to_match:
    case s if issubclass(type_to_match, str):
        print(f"{s} - This is a String")
    case n if issubclass(type_to_match, int):
        print(f"{n} - This is an Int")
    case _:
        print("\nhttps://en.meming.world/images/en/0/03/I%27ve_Never_Met_This_Man_In_My_Life.jpg")
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to grab the type name and match on that instead of on the type directly:

```py
from typing import Type

def main(type_to_match: Type):
    match type_to_match.__name__:
        case 'str':
            print("This is a String")
        case 'int':
            print("This is an Int")
        case _:
            print("\nhttps://en.meming.world/images/en/0/03/I%27ve_Never_Met_This_Man_In_My_Life.jpg")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_type = str
    main(test_type)
```