# Why does my match/case statement not work for class members?

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I'm finally using a Python version with support for the `match` statement, and was surprised that one of my `case`s didn't match. It seems to work fine for local or global variables, but not class/object members.

I've boiled it down to this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

globl = None

class MyObj(object):
    pass

def check(v):
    global globl
    globl = 2
    m = MyObj()
    m.val = 2
    local = 2
    match v:
        case globl:
            print(v, 'globl OK', globl)
    match v:
        case local:
            print(v, 'local OK', local)
    match v:
        case m.val:
            print(v, 'm.val OK', m.val)

check(1)
check(2)
check(3)
```

...which gives this output:

```
tmp$ ./match-experiment.py
1 globl OK 1
1 local OK 1
2 globl OK 2
2 local OK 2
2 m.val OK 2
3 globl OK 3
3 local OK 3
```

It looks like the global and local variable are used "by reference", while the class member is used "by value". So the normal variables are assigned the matched-on value, as I expect, but the class member `case` is only executed when the current value of that variable is equal to the matched-on `v`.

Why does the match/case statement not work for class members?

Comment: This is a good reference question to have; I couldn't find an obvious existing version of it, and the example and explanation are both good. However, I don't really understand the comparison you're drawing to parameter passing semantics (referring to "by reference"/"by value" concepts). "Class members" is probably not the right terminology for what you mean here, either.

Comment: "Brought to you by the mind of a C programmer". ;)  I can't think of better terms to describe it, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Somehow related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66159432/how-to-use-values-stored-in-variables-as-case-patterns

Answer (score 3):

You are dealing with two very different patterns. `match whatever` defines a subject.

`case globl:` is a [Capture Pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#capture-patterns). Its job is to assign the subject to `globl`. It doesn't consider the current value of `globl` which is unceremoniously deleted when the case succeeds. You could add `print("globl", globl)` after calling `check(1)` and you'll that the value has been reassigned.

`case m.val` is a [Value Pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#value-patterns). It does what you might expect: It looks up the value in `m.val` and uses that object to compare against the subject.

When you ran `check(1)`, the subject is `1`. `case globl` always succeeds and binds `globl` to the subject. `case m.val` gets the value `2` which doesn't match.

There is a certain lack of symmetry here and I think that capture patterns are more than a little surprising. You can't simply define constants and use them in a match. Suppose you are interested in a couple of socket errors. This doesn't compile because the first `case` will always match (and assign whatever happens to be in `err` to the `EAI_BADFLAGS` that you thought was constant).

```
from socket import EAI_BADFLAGS, EAI_AGAIN
err = -3 # for test
match err:
    case EAI_BADFLAGS:
        print("bad")
    case EAI_AGAIN:
        print("again")
```

But this works fine

```
import socket
err = -3 # for test
match err:
    case socket.EAI_BADFLAGS:
        print("bad")
    case socket.EAI_AGAIN:
        print("again")
```

And here I thought regular expressions were confusing!

Answer (score 1):

This is according to the spec of the `match` statement.

[PEP 622 says](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#patterns) (with italics added by me):

> A **capture pattern** looks like x and is equivalent to an identical assignment target: it always matches and binds the variable with the given *(simple) name*.
> [...]
> A **constant value pattern** works like the literal but for certain named constants. Note that *it must be a qualified (dotted) name*, given the possible ambiguity with a capture pattern. It looks like Color.RED and only matches values equal to the corresponding value. It never binds.

This means that:

- you can *not* match on the current value of a "plain" (or "simple") variable
- you can *only* match on the current value of a class member (never make `match` assign to it)

PEP 622 was not accepted, but this concept lives on (somewhat less clearly, in my opinion) in the accepted [PEP 634](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/#value-patterns):

> The dotted name in the pattern is looked up using the standard Python name resolution rules. [...] The pattern succeeds if the value found thus compares equal to the subject value (using the == operator).

PEP 636, the tutorial for match statements, [spells it out a bit more explicitly](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#matching-against-constants-and-enums):

> This will work with any dotted name (like math.pi). However an unqualified name (i.e. a bare name with no dots) will be always interpreted as a capture pattern, so avoid that ambiguity by always using qualified constants in patterns.

The [PEP 622 Alternatives for constant value pattern](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#alternatives-for-constant-value-pattern) and [PEP 635 Value Patterns](https://peps.python.org/pep-0635/#value-patterns) sections discuss the alternatives that were considered, and why they were rejected.