how do you make a tkinter combobox that can switch a given widget type to another widget type in a specific place
so specifically i wanted to make two comboboxes,  a button.   along with 8 other widgets to switch between,  in 8 widget "places" (specific areas where i put the widgets)
the first combo switches the place,  and the second switches the widget.  the button executes this
(spinbox, entrybox, combobox, radionbutton, checkbutton, scale, progressbar, and listbox)
the premise for this project was:
"Create 2 Comboboxes that switch a particular widget to another widget
Manage 8  widgets,   have the first Combobox switch the widget being manipulated,  and the second Combobox switch that widget between the other widgets."
the problem i'm having with this is that there aren't any easy ways to do it in python (i'm specifically using tkinter/ttk)
when i tried using the widgets in functions.  they don't show up on screen. (i'm still new to tkinter this might be an obvious fix)  and no errors show up.  the GUi seems to work just fine.  but when the button calls the choose() function,  it goes straight to the else statement. which is probably a sign that the input it's getting isn't corrext
from tkinter import *



from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from time import *

# Global Variables
a = "Spinbox"
b = "Entrybox"
c = "Checkbox"
d = "RadioButton"
e = "Combobox"
f = "Listbox"
g = "Scale"
h = "Progressbar"
# GUI
root = Tk()
frame = ttk.Frame(root, style='color.TFrame')
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('color.TFrame', background='black', borderwidth=5,
            relief='sunken')
root.title("Widget Manipulator")
frame.grid(column=0,
           row=0)

root.columnconfigure(0,
                     weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0,
                  weight=1)


# Functions


def choose():
    place.get()
    if place == 1:
        place1()
    elif place == 2:
        place2()
    elif place == 3:
        place3()
    elif place == 4:
        place4()
    elif place == 5:
        place5()
    elif place == 6:
        place6()
    elif place == 7:
        place7()
    elif place == 8:
        place8()
    else:
        placetext.set("Please choose an Option for the place")


def place1():
    widget.get()
    if widget == a:
        ttk.Spinbox().grid(column=1, row=1)
    elif widget == b:
        ttk.Entry().grid(column=1, row=1)
    elif widget == c:
        ttk.Checkbutton().grid(column=1, row=1)
    elif widget == d:
        ttk.Radiobutton().grid(column=1, row=1)
    elif widget == e:
        ttk.Combobox().grid(column=1, row=1)
    elif widget == f:
        Listbox().grid(column=1, row=1)
    elif widget == g:
        ttk.Scale().grid(column=1, row=1)
    elif widget == h:
        ttk.Progressbar().grid(column=1, row=1)
    else:
        widgettext.set("please enter widget")


def place2():
    widget.get()
    if widget == a:
        ttk.Spinbox().grid(column=1, row=2)
    elif widget == b:
        ttk.Entry().grid(column=1, row=2)
    elif widget == c:
        ttk.Checkbutton().grid(column=1, row=2)
    elif widget == d:
        ttk.Radiobutton().grid(column=1, row=2)
    elif widget == e:
        ttk.Combobox().grid(column=1, row=2)
    elif widget == f:
        Listbox().grid(column=1, row=2)
    elif widget == g:
        ttk.Scale().grid(column=1, row=2)
    elif widget == h:
        ttk.Progressbar().grid(column=1, row=2)
    else:
        widgettext.set("please enter widget")


def place3():
    widget.get()
    if widget == a:
        ttk.Spinbox().grid(column=1, row=3)
    elif widget == b:
        ttk.Entry().grid(column=1, row=3)
    elif widget == c:
        ttk.Checkbutton().grid(column=1, row=3)
    elif widget == d:
        ttk.Radiobutton().grid(column=1, row=3)
    elif widget == e:
        ttk.Combobox().grid(column=1, row=3)
    elif widget == f:
        Listbox().grid(column=1, row=3)
    elif widget == g:
        ttk.Scale().grid(column=1, row=3)
    elif widget == h:
        ttk.Progressbar().grid(column=1, row=3)
    else:
        widgettext.set("please enter widget")


def place4():
    widget.get()
    if widget == a:
        ttk.Spinbox().grid(column=1, row=4)
    elif widget == b:
        ttk.Entry().grid(column=1, row=4)
    elif widget == c:
        ttk.Checkbutton().grid(column=1, row=4)
    elif widget == d:
        ttk.Radiobutton().grid(column=1, row=4)
    elif widget == e:
        ttk.Combobox().grid(column=1, row=4)
    elif widget == f:
        Listbox().grid(column=1, row=4)
    elif widget == g:
        ttk.Scale().grid(column=1, row=4)
    elif widget == h:
        ttk.Progressbar().grid(column=1, row=4)
    else:
        widgettext.set("please enter widget")


def place5():
    widget.get()
    if widget == a:
        ttk.Spinbox().grid(column=1, row=5)
    elif widget == b:
        ttk.Entry().grid(column=1, row=5)
    elif widget == c:
        ttk.Checkbutton().grid(column=1, row=5)
    elif widget == d:
        ttk.Radiobutton().grid(column=1, row=5)
    elif widget == e:
        ttk.Combobox().grid(column=1, row=5)
    elif widget == f:
        Listbox().grid(column=1, row=5)
    elif widget == g:
        ttk.Scale().grid(column=1, row=5)
    elif widget == h:
        ttk.Progressbar().grid(column=1, row=5)
    else:
        widgettext.set("please enter widget")


def place6():
    widget.get()
    if widget == a:
        ttk.Spinbox().grid(column=1, row=6)
    elif widget == b:
        ttk.Entry().grid(column=1, row=6)
    elif widget == c:
        ttk.Checkbutton().grid(column=1, row=6)
    elif widget == d:
        ttk.Radiobutton().grid(column=1, row=6)
    elif widget == e:
        ttk.Combobox().grid(column=1, row=6)
    elif widget == f:
        Listbox().grid(column=1, row=6)
    elif widget == g:
        ttk.Scale().grid(column=1, row=6)
    elif widget == h:
        ttk.Progressbar().grid(column=1, row=6)
    else:
        widgettext.set("please enter widget")


def place7():
    widget.get()
    if widget == a:
        ttk.Spinbox().grid(column=1, row=7)
        root.update()
    elif widget == b:
        ttk.Entry().grid(column=1, row=7)
    elif widget == c:
        ttk.Checkbutton().grid(column=1, row=7)
    elif widget == d:
        ttk.Radiobutton().grid(column=1, row=7)
    elif widget == e:
        ttk.Combobox().grid(column=1, row=7)
    elif widget == f:
        Listbox().grid(column=1, row=7)
    elif widget == g:
        ttk.Scale().grid(column=1, row=7)
    elif widget == h:
        ttk.Progressbar().grid(column=1, row=7)
    else:
        widgettext.set("please enter widget")


def place8():
    widget.get()
    if widget == a:
        ttk.Spinbox().grid(column=1, row=8)
    elif widget == b:
        ttk.Entry().grid(column=1, row=8)
    elif widget == c:
        ttk.Checkbutton().grid(column=1, row=8)
    elif widget == d:
        ttk.Radiobutton().grid(column=1, row=8)
    elif widget == e:
        ttk.Combobox().grid(column=1, row=8)
    elif widget == f:
        Listbox().grid(column=1, row=8)
    elif widget == g:
        ttk.Scale().grid(column=1, row=8)
    elif widget == h:
        ttk.Progressbar().grid(column=1, row=8)
    else:
        widgettext.set("please enter widget")


# Widgets
place = IntVar()
widget = StringVar()
placetext = StringVar()
widgettext = StringVar()
Label(frame, textvariable=placetext).grid(column=2,
                                          row=1)
Label(frame, textvariable=widgettext).grid(column=0,
                                           row=1)
Button(frame, text="Change",
       command=choose).grid(column=1,
                            row=0)
ttk.Combobox(frame, textvariable=widget,
             values=(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)).grid(column=0,
                                                   row=0)
ttk.Combobox(frame, textvariable=place,
             values=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)).grid(column=2,
                                                   row=0)

root.mainloop()

This is the code i wrote for it (it's not finished)
i think there is a problem with the textvariables.   they don't seem to be working the way i intended  (i.e,  i called them with place.get(), widget.get(), etc. and they fetch the data and it runs through the if statements until it finds whiever widget and place it needs to go (then it's supposes to execute that eidget,  but for some reason widgets don't like to be in functions?)
i just don't understand why it isn't working.  or rather i don't understand what isn't working
it could be that i need to use root.update() to get the widgets to work.  but that doesn't matter if i can't get textvariables to put out the right stuff. oh and you can ignore the place functions beyond place1(),  they are identical outside of the their grid() methods.

place.get() (and various similar lines) retrieved the value of the Var - and then threw it away without doing anything with it.  You need to save that result into a variable, and then use that variable in further comparisons, rather than comparing things to the Var itself (which can never be equal).

And how would one do that? Place = StringVar() then a = place.get()?

So you got a partial answer already, but there's a number of things I want to point out.
First, you can simply use place.get() as any other int/str/whatever. So you can just use it directly in your if statements. Using a single choice = place.get() can be used as well, and this would make sense if you need to access the value a gazillion times in the function. However,
Second, the if/elif/else is no longer needed. Starting from python 3.10 there's a case/switch statement available (took way too long for that to be implemented, but that's a different can of worms).
There's one weird drawback in this though, the match/case statement doesn't like direct variables, and as per this answer there's a relatively easy fix. Be sure to also change the relevant assignment in your combobox.
The if/elif/else statements in the choose() function don't make sense, and the 8 place functions make even less sense. Code duplication is really an antipattern that can very easily lead to code spaghetti and increases the chances of bugs.
You're using the value from place as the row so you can directly pass that to the function that sets the row for the widget. Or you could just use the place.get() directly in that function.
Another thing to take into account is that you're not keeping track of the actual placed widgets. There's nothing stopping you from placing 9001 different widgets in the same row.
This is likely unwanted behavior, so you will need to keep track of the widget. So, create a list to hold the widgets. This also solves the problem that you cannot access the created widgets easily, as they are not assigned to a variable directly. Whether this is intended or not is not for me to determine.
### NO CHANGE HERE
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
frame = ttk.Frame(root, style="color.TFrame")
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure("color.TFrame", background="black", borderwidth=5, relief="sunken")
root.title("Widget Manipulator")
frame.grid(column=0, row=0)

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


### CODE BELOW CHANGES
# this link explains the needed usage of a class
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/66159622/9267296
class WidgetTypes:
    a = "Spinbox"
    b = "Entrybox"
    c = "Checkbox"
    d = "RadioButton"
    e = "Combobox"
    f = "Listbox"
    g = "Scale"
    h = "Progressbar"


# create a list with 8*None to prevent out of bound errors
# Since lists are zero-indexed, we put a dummy value in index 0
# in prod, this should be another None to reduce resource usage
widget_list = ["0-indexed workaround", None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]


def choose():
    if place.get() >= 1 and place.get() <= 8:
        place_widget(place.get())
    else:
        placetext.set("Please choose an Option for the place")


def place_widget(choice: int):
    # this only works in python 3.10+
    # check if widget type is selected and also if row
    # is already existing widget and destroy if needed
    # this will prevent memory leaks (I think)
    if widget.get() != "" and widget_list[choice] != None:
        widget_list[choice].destroy()

    match widget.get():
        case WidgetTypes.a:
            widget_list[choice] = ttk.Spinbox()
            widget_list[choice].grid(column=1, row=choice)
        case WidgetTypes.b:
            widget_list[choice] = ttk.Entry()
            widget_list[choice].grid(column=1, row=choice)
        case WidgetTypes.c:
            widget_list[choice] = ttk.Checkbutton()
            widget_list[choice].grid(column=1, row=choice)
        case WidgetTypes.d:
            widget_list[choice] = ttk.Radiobutton()
            widget_list[choice].grid(column=1, row=choice)
        case WidgetTypes.e:
            widget_list[choice] = ttk.Combobox()
            widget_list[choice].grid(column=1, row=choice)
        case WidgetTypes.f:
            widget_list[choice] = Listbox()
            widget_list[choice].grid(column=1, row=choice)
        case WidgetTypes.g:
            widget_list[choice] = ttk.Scale()
            widget_list[choice].grid(column=1, row=choice)
        case WidgetTypes.h:
            widget_list[choice] = ttk.Progressbar()
            widget_list[choice].grid(column=1, row=choice)
        case _:  # this is the final catch-all statement.
            widgettext.set("please enter widget")


# Widgets
place = IntVar()
widget = StringVar()
placetext = StringVar()
widgettext = StringVar()
Label(frame, textvariable=placetext).grid(column=2, row=1)
Label(frame, textvariable=widgettext).grid(column=0, row=1)
Button(frame, text="Change", command=choose).grid(column=1, row=0)
ttk.Combobox(
    frame,
    textvariable=widget,
    values=(
        WidgetTypes.a,
        WidgetTypes.b,
        WidgetTypes.c,
        WidgetTypes.d,
        WidgetTypes.e,
        WidgetTypes.f,
        WidgetTypes.g,
        WidgetTypes.h,
    ),
).grid(column=0, row=0)
ttk.Combobox(frame, textvariable=place, values=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)).grid(
    column=2, row=0
)

root.mainloop()


Whoa.  I didn't know much about match and case (know of any good resources on that point?). This is really helpful.  Im still a novice at Python so I'm going to study this code for bit.  (Classes aren't a strongsuit of mine) But from reading it i've been able to understand it for the most part.  I haven't programmed anything that has led to a memory leak.  So I didn't even think of that(Im not too sure what that is tho)

TBH I didn't know about match/case up until recently. You can use if/elif/else same as you were doing in your own code, and change the class back to simple variables. This usage of a class is absolute simplest though. In this case (pun intended) you can see it as a simple container to group the abc variables.

As for memory leaks, it's not something you need to worry about often, but one of the ways to leak memory is to create objects without ever destroying them. Each object needs a bit of memory to store its variables. Good practice is to destroy an object as soon as you no longer need it, but in python specifically, you can skip a lot of this due to how scopes work in python. Tkinter throws a bit of a wrench in the normal way as you attach objects (eg. Spinbox, Combobox, etc) to the grid, and they then become part of the global scope.

For resources, w3schools is an extremely good starting point, as they explain stuff simply and succinctly. Another good one that tends to go a bit more in-depth is Real Python and they explain classes quite in-depth. Note that in programming in general, objects and classes are a subject that is fundamental. Also, of course reddit has a sub for this.
